# Php Javascript Google API pie chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts

Hi I'm currently working on a google chart with on change drop down that will update the table and pie chart, The setup is we have a list of department and the goal is to sort the data by department. The table works fine but the pie chart only update once. (I use mysql for the database)

```
    //pieChart_Holder.php

        <html>
<body onload = "searchq();">
<select name="option" >
<option selected="selected">All</option>
<option>external</option>
<option>internal</option>
</select>

<select id="myselect">
    <option value="finance">Finance</option>
    <option value="prod_management">Product Management</option>
    <option value="HR">Human Resources</option>
    <option value="tsi">TSI</option>
    <option value="tso">TSO</option>
    <option value="corp_plan">Corporate Planning</option>
    <option value="sca">SCA</option>
    <option value="com_management">Commercial Management</option>
    <option value="d_a">Design & Architecture</option>
    <option value="sd_fm">SD-FM</option>
    <option value="sd_pm">SD-PM</option>
    <option value="sale">Sales</option>
    <option value="scm">SCM</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  
<script type = "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var drop_down,test;

<?php  




session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "trial");  


 if(isset($_POST['dropVal1_self'])){
     $holder1 = $_POST['dropVal1_self'];
        if($holder1=="finance") 
            {
        $dept_type='Finance';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type; 
    } 
    elseif ($holder1=="prod_management"){
        $dept_type='Product Management';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="HR"){
        $dept_type='Human Resources';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="tsi"){
        $dept_type='TSI';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="tso"){
        $dept_type='TSO';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="corp_plan"){
        $dept_type='Corporate Planning';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="sca"){
        $dept_type='SCA';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="com_management"){
        $dept_type='Commercial Management';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="d_a"){
        $dept_type='Design & Architecture';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="sd_fm"){
        $dept_type='SD-FM';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="sd_pm"){
        $dept_type='SD-PM';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;

    }
    elseif ($holder1=="sale"){
        $dept_type='Sales';
    $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="scm"){
        $dept_type='SCM';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
    }                
} 
if (isset($_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"])){
 $dept_type = $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"];
 $query_Chart = "SELECT rate_desc, count(*) as number FROM internal WHERE date_extract IN (SELECT max(date_extract) FROM internal WHERE survey_dept = '$dept_type') GROUP BY rate_desc";  
 $result_chart = mysqli_query($connect, $query_Chart);  

  }
 else {
 $dept_type = 'Finance';
$query_Chart = "SELECT rate_desc, count(*) as number FROM internal WHERE date_extract IN (SELECT max(date_extract) FROM internal WHERE survey_dept = '$dept_type') GROUP BY rate_desc";  
$result_chart = mysqli_query($connect, $query_Chart);  
 }


 ?>  
//Chart
       google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});  

       function drawChart()  
       {  
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
                      ['rate_desc', 'Number'],  
                      <?php  
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_chart))  
                      {  
                           echo "['".$row["rate_desc"]."', ".$row["number"]."],";  
                      }  
                      ?>  
                 ]);  
            var options = {  
                  title: 'chart',  
                   is3D:true,
                    slices: {
                    0: { color: 'red' },
                    1: { color: 'yellow' },
                    2: { color: 'green' },
                            }          
                  //pieHole: 0.4,  
                 };  
            var chart = new                 google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));  
            chart.draw(data, options);  
       }  

function searchq(){
var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
$.post("s5_filter.php",{searchVal:searchTxt}, function(output) {
    $("#output").html(output)
}); 
}
$( "select" )
.change(function (drop_down,test) {
    drop_down = $("select option:selected").val();
    $.post("s5_filter.php",{dropVal:drop_down}, function(output) {
    $("#output").html(output)
    // drawChart();   
});

    test = $( "#myselect" ).val();
    $.post("s5_filter.php",{dropVal1:test}, function(output){
    $("#output").html(output)   
    drawChart();  
});

    var test1 = $( "#myselect" ).val();
    $.post("pieChart_Holder.php",{dropVal1_self:test1}, function(piechart){


});

})
.change();

</script>
<form action="" method = "POST">
<input type="text" name="search"  onkeyup= "searchq();" />
</form>



<div id = "output">
</div>
       <div style="width:900px;">  
            <br />  
            <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>  
       </div>  
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

s5_filter.php
this is where it passes it values

```
  //s5_filter.php
 <style type="text/css">
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
</style>

<?php
    session_start();
        function testing_sql($conn,$output) {
    if(isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
        $searchq = $_POST['searchVal']or die("");
        $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
        }
    else{
        $searchq='';
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION["dropdown_query1"])){
        $holder = $_SESSION["dropdown_query1"]or die("");
        }
        else{
            $holder ='';
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"])){
            $dept_holder = $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"];
        }
        else{
                $dept_holder ='Finance';
        }

        echo "$holder";
    if ($holder=='internal'){

            if ($searchq==''){
            $query= "SELECT * FROM internal WHERE survey_dept = '$dept_holder' AND survey_type = '$holder'";
            }
            else {
                echo "internal"; 
            $query= "SELECT * FROM internal WHERE survey_type = '$holder' AND survey_dept ='$dept_holder' AND (RespondID LIKE '%$searchq%' OR CollectorID LIKE '%$searchq%' OR startDate LIKE '%$searchq%' OR endDate LIKE '%$searchq%'OR IPAddress LIKE '%$searchq%' OR email LIKE '%$searchq%'OR firstName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR lastName LIKE '%$searchq%'OR customData LIKE '%$searchq%' OR recentTrans LIKE '%$searchq%'OR others LIKE '%$searchq%' OR rate LIKE '%$searchq%'OR explanation LIKE '%$searchq%' OR suggestions LIKE '%$searchq%'OR empName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR empId LIKE '%$searchq%')";
            }
            }
        else if ($holder=='external'){

            if ($searchq==''){
            $query= "SELECT * FROM internal WHERE survey_dept = '$dept_holder' AND survey_type = '$holder'";
            }
            else {
            echo "external"; 
        $query= "SELECT * FROM internal WHERE survey_type = '$holder' AND survey_dept ='$dept_holder' AND (RespondID LIKE '%$searchq%' OR CollectorID LIKE '%$searchq%' OR startDate LIKE '%$searchq%' OR endDate LIKE '%$searchq%'OR IPAddress LIKE '%$searchq%' OR email LIKE '%$searchq%'OR firstName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR lastName LIKE '%$searchq%'OR customData LIKE '%$searchq%' OR recentTrans LIKE '%$searchq%'OR others LIKE '%$searchq%' OR rate LIKE '%$searchq%'OR explanation LIKE '%$searchq%' OR suggestions LIKE '%$searchq%'OR empName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR empId LIKE '%$searchq%')";
            }
    }
    else{
        if ($searchq==''){
                    echo"working else"; 
            $query= "SELECT * FROM internal WHERE survey_dept = '$dept_holder'";
        }
        else{
        echo"working else"; 
        $query= "SELECT * FROM internal WHERE survey_dept = '$dept_holder' AND (RespondID LIKE '%$searchq%' OR CollectorID LIKE '%$searchq%' OR startDate LIKE '%$searchq%' OR endDate LIKE '%$searchq%'OR IPAddress LIKE '%$searchq%' OR email LIKE '%$searchq%'OR firstName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR lastName LIKE '%$searchq%'OR customData LIKE '%$searchq%' OR recentTrans LIKE '%$searchq%'OR others LIKE '%$searchq%' OR rate LIKE '%$searchq%'OR explanation LIKE '%$searchq%' OR suggestions LIKE '%$searchq%'OR empName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR empId LIKE '%$searchq%' OR survey_type LIKE '%$searchq%')";
        }
    }

    //$query= "SELECT * FROM internal WHERE RespondID LIKE '%$searchq%' OR CollectorID LIKE '%$searchq%' OR startDate LIKE '%$searchq%' OR endDate LIKE '%$searchq%'OR IPAddress LIKE '%$searchq%' OR email LIKE '%$searchq%'OR firstName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR lastName LIKE '%$searchq%'OR customData LIKE '%$searchq%' OR recentTrans LIKE '%$searchq%'OR others LIKE '%$searchq%' OR rate LIKE '%$searchq%'OR explanation LIKE '%$searchq%' OR suggestions LIKE '%$searchq%'OR empName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR empId LIKE '%$searchq%' OR survey_dept LIKE '%$searchq%'OR survey_type LIKE '%$searchq%'";


    //$query= "SELECT * FROM internal WHERE RespondID LIKE '%$searchq%' OR CollectorID LIKE '%$searchq%' OR startDate LIKE '%$searchq%' OR endDate LIKE '%$searchq%'OR IPAddress LIKE '%$searchq%' OR email LIKE '%$searchq%'OR firstName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR lastName LIKE '%$searchq%'OR customData LIKE '%$searchq%' OR recentTrans LIKE '%$searchq%'OR others LIKE '%$searchq%' OR rate LIKE '%$searchq%'OR explanation LIKE '%$searchq%' OR suggestions LIKE '%$searchq%'OR empName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR empId LIKE '%$searchq%' OR survey_dept LIKE '%$searchq%'OR survey_type LIKE '%$searchq%'";       
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)or die ("database error"); 
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result); 


    //----------------------Search with results---------------------------------------------------------------------        
    if($count == 0){
        $output = 'no results';
     }else {

            echo "<table border = 1>
                <tr>
                <th>RespondID</th>
                <th>CollectorID</th>
                <th>startDate</th>
                <th>endDate</th>
                <th>IPAddress</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>firstName</th>
                <th>lastName</th>
                <th>customData</th>
                <th>recentTrans</th>
                <th>others</th>
                <th>rate</th>
                <th>rate_desc</th>
                <th>explanation</th>
                <th>suggestions</th>
                <th>empName</th>
                <th>empId</th>
                <th>survey_type</th>
                <th>survey_dept</th>
                </tr>";



     // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
       echo "<tr>"; 
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["RespondID"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["CollectorID"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["startDate"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["endDate"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["IPAddress"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["email"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["firstName"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["lastName"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["customData"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["recentTrans"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["others"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["rate"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["rate_desc"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["explanation"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["suggestions"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["empName"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["empId"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["survey_type"]) . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . str_replace($searchq, "<span class=\"highlight\">$searchq</span>",$row["survey_dept"]) . "</td>";


     echo "</tr>";     
          }
         echo "</table>";


     }



print("$output");   
}





  $conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "trial") or die ("WALA");
  $output = "";
 if(isset($_POST['dropVal1'])){
 $holder1 = $_POST['dropVal1'];
    if($holder1=="finance") 
    {
        echo("Finance");
        $dept_type='Finance';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
        testing_sql($conn,$output); 
    } 
    elseif ($holder1=="prod_management"){
        echo("Product Management");
        $dept_type='Product Management';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
        testing_sql($conn,$output); 
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="HR"){
        $dept_type='Human Resources';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
        testing_sql($conn,$output); 
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="tsi"){
        $dept_type='TSI';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
        testing_sql($conn,$output);
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="tso"){
        $dept_type='TSO';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
        testing_sql($conn,$output);
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="corp_plan"){
        $dept_type='Corporate Planning';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
        testing_sql($conn,$output);
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="sca"){
        $dept_type='SCA';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
        testing_sql($conn,$output);
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="com_management"){
        $dept_type='Commercial Management';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
        testing_sql($conn,$output);
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="d_a"){
        $dept_type='Design & Architecture';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
        testing_sql($conn,$output);
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="sd_fm"){
        $dept_type='SD-FM';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
        testing_sql($conn,$output);
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="sd_pm"){
        $dept_type='SD-PM';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type
        testing_sql($conn,$output);
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="sale"){
        $dept_type='Sales';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
        testing_sql($conn,$output);
    }
    elseif ($holder1=="scm"){
        $dept_type='SCM';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_survey_query"] = $dept_type;
        testing_sql($conn,$output); 
    }                   

    }    

    if(isset($_POST['dropVal'])){
    ///SEARCH POST VALUE

         $dropdown = $_POST['dropVal'];


    if ($dropdown == 'internal'){
        $dropdown_query = 'internal';
    $_SESSION["dropdown_query1"] = $dropdown_query;
            testing_sql($conn,$output);
    }
    else if ($dropdown == 'external'){

        $dropdown_query = 'external';
        $_SESSION["dropdown_query1"] = $dropdown_query;
                testing_sql($conn,$output);
    }
        else{

            $dropdown_query = 'All';
            $_SESSION["dropdown_query1"] = $dropdown_query;
                    testing_sql($conn,$output);
    }

        }



        //search---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if(isset($_POST['searchVal'])){

 testing_sql($conn,$output); 
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Ajax with internal for "**s5_filter.php**".
Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         // first load it once, so it display's the chart 
         // (otherwise you have to wait 5 seconds)
         $('#piechart').load('s5_filter.php');
         // then execute the interval
        setInterval(function(){$('#piechart').load('s5_filter.php');},
 5000);
     }); </script>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I need to update the piechart everytime the user changes the dropdown

Comment: 1) Call onChange Event and get the selected value <br />
 $('#myselect').onChange(refresh_my_chart(this.value)); <br /> <br />
2) create a function refresh_my_chart(dd_val) and receive the selected item value
<br />
`code`function refresh_my_chart(dd_val) {  $('#piechart').load('s5_filter.php?dd_val='+dd_val); }
Pass the selected value to your filter file & get the list on the based of your item.
<br />Hope this help.